# pureMVC: unique mediator for each tab in an interface

Tags: apache-flex, puremvc, mediator

I am building a tabbed interface for switching between various similar layers.  Each layer will have a number of graphs.  By dragging with the mouse the graphs can be rearranged or even moved between layers.  My question is, is it best practice to register a unique mediator for each layer that keeps track of the layers content / organization, or should i keep track of it all with one central mediator.

**some considerations:**

the layer contents and organization will be saved(in a db) so that it can be restored when a user comes back to the app.

the layers themselves are functionally identical.

the user can add and remove layers at will.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sort of use I will generally mediate each screen in a tabbed interface individually by passing in a unique identifier with the constructor of the mediator. The layers won't require different mediator classes, just different mediator instances with unique names that are easy to retrieve. I typically override *getMediatorName* and return NAME + uniqueId.